# Jboss Deployment fails when added contextlistener

Tags: xml, spring, rest, jboss, jersey

My Jboss deployment fails when I added contextlistener, Doyou have any idea.
I am using spring 3.2, jersey 2, jboss 5.1 eap, I have necessary libs.
here is error

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:myapp.war

  jboss-as/server/default/tmp/myapp.war/ deployment failed
  <!--web.xml-->


   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
     <display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>myapp.resources.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Rest Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

My applicationContext.xml location is in web/WEB-INF/Classes
```

can you please help me, I Cleaned up data, tmp, work folders all the time, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you add exception stacktrace?

Comment: i fixed it, issue is with missing jars. but i still have problem in accessing entitymanager from rest /jersey